# Tshark logging by local username

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, packet-capture, tshark

I'm trying to attribute network traffic in a tshark dump with the logged in user that the respective traffic is associated with.

I'm running an Ubuntu server on a corporate network in which users log into either via RDP or SSH with x-forwarding. My application is written in bash and uses tshark to log all network traffic using the following command:

```
 tshark -b filesize:1024 -w traffic.pcap
```

I then have a while loop that runs on a chron job to parse through the pcap files, extract the fields I want, and save them to json:

```
for f in *.pcap
do
    tshark -r $f -T json > $f.json
    cat $f.json | jq .[]._source.layers | jq -r '.frame_time_epoch[],.frame_number[],.tcp_stream[],.ip_src[],.tcp_srcport[],.ip_dst[],.tcp_dstport[],.frame_len[],.frame_protocols[],.http_host[],.http_request_uri[],.http_request_method[],.http_user_agent[],.http_referer[],.dns_qry_name[],.dns_resp_name[],.ssl_handshake_extensions_server_name[],.x509sat_uTF8String[],.x509ce_dNSName,"END"' > injest.json
done
```

The output json which looks like the following is then sent to an Elasticsearch cluster I have set up:

```
{
"layers": {
    "frame.time_epoch": ["1579755811.545369005"],
    "frame.number": ["3508"],
    "tcp.stream": ["0"],
    "ip.src": ["10.0.10.10"],
    "tcp.srcport": ["22"],
    "ip.dst": ["1.1.1.1"],
    "tcp.dstport": ["54116"],
    "frame.len": ["102"],
    "frame.protocols": ["eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:ssh"]
    }
}
```

I'd like to know if there is anyway I can have the Linux username added to the packet capture or as an additional field in the final json before it is sent to ELK.

In other words if 'user_a' and 'user_b' are both logged into the server I'd like their respective internet traffic to log there usernames. Is this at all possible with tshark? I've read that iptables can "tag" traffic but I'm not sure exactly how it works and if it would accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Adding the usernames to the packet capture is a different question than adding the usernames to tshark output to be sent to your elasticsearch deployment. If bash is involved here, you should include it so that this question is on-topic for Stack Overflow (i.e. programming-related) and to provide more context.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I have a series of bash scripts that runs Tshark, saves the output, and sends it to ELK.

Comment: Good. There is an edit button below your question. You should also read Stack Overflow's [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Edited to include code snippets and a clarification of how the application currently works and what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Logging users by packets sent

> I'd like to know if there is anyway I can have the Linux username added to the packet capture

This is possible by adding a capture comment as detailed below

> or as an additional field in the final json before it is sent to ELK.

while this is not because tshark does not know how to show you pcapng header options, even though it can read them (Wireshark can do this with `reload as file format/capture`).

> In other words if 'user_a' and 'user_b' are both logged into the server I'd like their respective internet traffic to log their usernames. Is this at all possible with tshark?

No, this is not possible with tshark. It looks like [it's](https://serverfault.com/questions/192893/how-i-can-identify-which-process-is-making-udp-traffic-on-linux) [possible](https://serverfault.com/questions/666482/how-to-find-out-pid-of-the-process-sending-packets-generating-network-traffic) to use auditctl to get the PIDs, and then find the users that created the PIDs. With the usernames thusly gathered, you could integrate into the flow below.

### Adding a capture comment

To get the active usernames, you can use something like this:

```sh
names="$(who | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort | uniq)"
```

To save as part of the packet capture, use tshark's --capture-comment to add additional information. Note that this option is only available if you save as pcapng. The default save-type is pcapng. If you're unsure, you can use `captype $file`, where captype comes with Wireshark.

```
tshark -b filesize:1024 -w traffic.pcap --capture-comment "$names"
```

### Extracting the capture comment

tshark doesn't have a way to extract a capture-level comment, so I'm using python, with knowledge of [pcapng's binary format](http://xml2rfc.tools.ietf.org/cgi-bin/xml2rfc.cgi?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcapng/pcapng/master/draft-tuexen-opsawg-pcapng.xml&modeAsFormat=html/ascii&type=ascii) to extract the comment:

```py
import struct

def read_header(infile, header_code):
  with open(infile, "rb") as f:
      filebytes = f.read()
  header_len = struct.unpack("iill", filebytes[:24])[1]
  header = filebytes[24:24+header_len]
  seek = 24
  while seek < header_len:
      opt_code, opt_length = struct.unpack("hh", filebytes[seek:seek+4])
      if opt_code == header_code:
          value = filebytes[seek+4:seek+4+opt_length].decode('utf-8')
          return value
      seek += 4 + opt_length
  return ""

comment_option_code = 1
comment = read_header("traffic.pcap", comment_option_code)
print(comment)
```

Provided a user_a and user_b in `$names`, this would then print

```sh
user_a user_b
```

### Adding to the JSON

You can then append the data to your existing json like so:

```sh
echo '{"data": "values"}' | jq --arg names "${names}" '. + {users:$names}'
{
  "data": "values",
  "users": "user_a user_b"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful but I want to take this a step further. The solution you provided will list all active users at the time of a specific network communication. I'd like to actually attribute network traffic to a specific users.
In the following example: 'user_a' and 'user_b' are both logged into the server; 'user_a' makes a request to https://stackoverflow.com; 'user_b' makes a request to https://github.com; I'd like to be able to attribute the stackoverflow traffic to 'user_a' and the github traffic to 'user_b'.

Comment: Updated the answer to better answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give your solutions a shot and see if I can build this in. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Awesome! If this answers your question, please mark it as such.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use your suggestion to add user PID's to the network flow. I appreciate the help!